# How to print when a dict value changes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have currently worked on a comparison function where I want to be able to print out whenever there has been a change in a dict. What I currently do is that I send request to my local-api where it returns different values and here is the example:

```
First request

{
  '00194953243062': {
    'value': '00194953243062',
    'stock': 'OOS',
    'modificationDate': '2022-10-22T12:02:06.000Z'
  },
  '00194953243086': {
    'value': '00194953243086',
    'stock': 'OOS',
    'modificationDate': '2022-09-30T10:55:45.000Z'
  },
  '00194953243093': {
    'value': '00194953243093',
    'stock': 'OOS',
    'modificationDate': '2022-10-22T11:05:54.000Z'
  },
  '00194953243130': {
    'value': '00194953243130',
    'stock': 'OOS',
    'modificationDate': '2022-10-22T08:55:48.000Z'
  }
}

print("All values are OOS!")
****************************************************************************************************
Second request

{
  '00194953243062': {
    'value': '00194953243062',
    'stock': 'OOS',
    'modificationDate': '2022-10-22T12:02:06.000Z'
  },
  '00194953243086': {
    'value': '00194953243086',
    'stock': 'OOS',
    'modificationDate': '2022-09-30T10:55:45.000Z'
  },
  '00194953243093': {
    'value': '00194953243093',
    'stock': 'OOS',
    'modificationDate': '2022-10-22T11:05:54.000Z'
  },
  '00194953243130': {
    'value': '00194953243130',
    'stock': 'LOW',
    'modificationDate': '2022-10-22T08:55:48.000Z'
  }
}

print("New value has been found!")
****************************************************************************************************
Third request

{
  '00194953243062': {
    'value': '00194953243062',
    'stock': 'LOW',
    'modificationDate': '2022-10-22T12:02:06.000Z'
  },
  '00194953243086': {
    'value': '00194953243086',
    'stock': 'OOS',
    'modificationDate': '2022-09-30T10:55:45.000Z'
  },
  '00194953243093': {
    'value': '00194953243093',
    'stock': 'OOS',
    'modificationDate': '2022-10-22T11:05:54.000Z'
  },
  '00194953243130': {
    'value': '00194953243130',
    'stock': 'OOS',
    'modificationDate': '2022-10-22T08:55:48.000Z'
  }
}

print("New value has been found!")   
****************************************************************************************************
Forth request

{
  '00194953243062': {
    'value': '00194953243062',
    'stock': 'OOS',
    'modificationDate': '2022-10-22T12:02:06.000Z'
  },
  '00194953243086': {
    'value': '00194953243086',
    'stock': 'OOS',
    'modificationDate': '2022-09-30T10:55:45.000Z'
  },
  '00194953243093': {
    'value': '00194953243093',
    'stock': 'OOS',
    'modificationDate': '2022-10-22T11:05:54.000Z'
  },
  '00194953243130': {
    'value': '00194953243130',
    'stock': 'OOS',
    'modificationDate': '2022-10-22T08:55:48.000Z'
  }
}
print("All values are OOS!")
```

and the problem that I currently have is that I do not know how to print out whenever a stock value goes from OOS -> LOW -> then I should print out that there has been a restock and whenever the sizes goes from LOW -> OOS then I want to check if ALL stock values has the OOS then we should print out that "All values are OOS".

I have done something like this:

```
previous_data = {}
gtin = # Is the example I have given above

if previous_data.keys() != gtin.keys():
    if all(value['stock'].casefold() == 'oos' for att, value in gtin.items()):
        print("All values are OOS!")

    else:
        print("New value has been found!")

previous_data = gtin
```

but I noticed that I am missing where I check whenever a value goes from OOS -> LOW, I seem to only check the key of each key-value and therefore I seem to miss the "stock" value changes, I wonder how can I notify myself whenever a stock goes from OOS -> LOW/Whatever else besides OOS and NOT printing if it goes back to LOW -> OOS besides if all stock values are OOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first part will already notify you any time a change causes all items to be out of stock.

I think you just need an `elif` statement to follow it up. Something like this should work:

```
previous_data = {}
gtin = # Is the example I have given above

if not previous_data:
    print("collecting initial inventory")
elif previous_data.keys() == gtin.keys():
    # if our keys are the same we can check which values have changed based on your logic 
    if all(value['stock'].casefold() == 'oos' for att, value in gtin.items()):
        print("All values are OOS!")
    
    #only if they have changed to low, medium or high
    elif any(
            (value['stock'].casefold() in ['low', 'medium', 'high'] and 
            previous_data[att]['stock'].casefold() == 'oos') 
            for att, value in gtin.items()):
        print("New value has been found!")
else:
    # the dictionary keys dont match
    # so the size of your inventory has changed do some other logic 

previous_data = gtin
```

Comment: Hello! It seems like im getting an error when testing your code: `value['stock'] != previous_data[att]['stock']) KeyError: '00194953243062'` - My guess is that if previous_data is empty, it might be why? so I guess it would better to do: `previous_data.get(att, {}).get('stock', {})`

Comment: Yes, it will be because `previous_data` is empty to start with. How you deal with it depends on your use case. Once you have populated `previous_data` will the keys always stay the same with only the values changing? Or do you anticipate new keys being added? In either case, what's your desired output?

Comment: Its pretty hard to say as I am confused myself abit. But the point is similar to what you have done, What I want to basically do is 1. If all values are OOS then we print out that its all values are oos as the first `if-statement` but then if a value goes from OOS to either `low, medium or high` then we should print out `new value has been found` and I believe all I need to do is to change your first `if statement` which is `if previous_data.keys() != gtin.keys():` to instead `if previous_data != gtin:` because if we use keys then it wont see the stock difference.

Comment: It's hard to give you a definitive solution without knowing exactly what your use case is. If keys can be added / deleted then yes you don't want to just compare keys in the first if statement. But you will likely want to capture the exact changes, so using `.get()` and setting a default is probably not going to capture all your different use cases.

Comment: I'll update my answer to make the assumption the keys won't change once set

Comment: So the ideal of the whole process is that I want to check whenever a value goes from OOS to either `low, medium or hard` - So I only want to print whenever it goes from `OOS -> LOW/MEDIUM/HIGH` and nothing else, if it goes from `LOW -> MEDIUM` then we shouldn't print, Only whenever it goes from `OOS -> LOW/MEDIUM/HIGH` and if it goes from `LOW/MEDIUM/HIGH -> OOS` then it should `NOT` print it either.

Comment: Okay - I've update my answer to capture 'low', 'medium' or 'high' and the whole statement only runs if 'previous_data' is not empty. This will now work if the keys stays the same. However, if they change you will need to change this slightly

Comment: And by `if they change you will need to change this slightly` what do you mean by that? I mean will it print out if it goes from `LOW/MEDIUM/HIGH -> OOS`? and if yes, how cna I change it in that case?

Comment: I've updated it again for you to try and make it more clear. Your inventory is currently 4 items that don't change. It is not clear from your question if these stay constant or can change. The final `else` captures if this changes to a different number (e.g. 5) items.

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have mentioned but the example of the 4 items is that the request returns e.g. one of these, it can be change on every request or it could stay same for many hours so but that means that it does change every now and then. What example would go into the else statement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249083/discussion-between-ashsmith88-and-pythonnewbie).

Comment: Im in here :) Waiting for you response

Comment: Did you have the time to check? :) I have written more in the discussion chat.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few things on your code that might not be what you intend to happen.

**1. The stock check is only executed if your inventory keys change:**
The `if previous_data.keys() != gtin.keys():` only checks for changes in the inventory IDs. Therefore, following your example, the stock check is only executed for the first API request (because of `previous_data = {}`).

**2. You're not checking for value changes, but for the existence of non `oos` values:**
Depending on what you intend to print, this might be okay. If you don't care about changes, but only about reporting when something is not `oos` then your logic from line 5 works fine.

#### Suggested logic given your explanation

You want to keep track of stock status for any inventory item you get from the API, and only print when something went from `oos` to another value, or when everything is `oos`. The following code might do the trick.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
inv_stock = defaultdict(lambda: 'OOS') # Assign stock to 'OOS' by default

gtin = get_inventory() # Is the example given above
new_value = False
all_oos = True

for inv_id, status_dict in gtin.items():
  stock_status = status_dict['stock']
  if stock_status != 'OOS':
    all_oos = False
    if inv_stock[inv_id] != stock_status:
      new_value = True
  inv_stock[inv_id] = stock_status

if all_oos:
  print("All values are OOS!")
elif new_value:
  print("New value has been found!")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I agree with you! I guess the first answer 1. if I instead change from .keys() to just `if previous_data != gtin:` that would tell us that there has been a change in previous vs new data.

Comment: I also wanted to say that I do get an error for the first defaultdict `inv_stock = defaultdict('oos') # Assign stock to 'oos' by default TypeError: first argument must be callable or None`

Comment: My bad! I didn't get a chance to check the code. I fixed that specific problem, but bear in my mind I could have another bug somewhere. I'll try to find some time to actually run it later today.

Comment: As for the comparison, I guess that's okay. If you care about any change then it makes sense, but if you're only looking for stock updates then it's probably not necessary, and the code I submitted should cover that scenario

Comment: I already checked the code and is running as desired given your example. Let me know if it works for you